# How do I create a customized action bar in Kotlin fragment activity class

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-actionbar

I am trying to customise a fragment class and an activity class from Android Studio's Bottom Navigation Activity template to produce a customized action bar but the customized action bar does not appear when I run the app on the emulator.

Here is the customized activity class with the `initializeCustomActionBar()` method:

```
class CountriesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_countries)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        navView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_england, R.id.navigation_scotland, R.id.navigation_wales, R.id.navigation_nireland
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    fun initializeCustomActionBar() {

        val actionBar: android.app.ActionBar? = getActionBar()
        actionBar?.displayOptions = DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
        actionBar?.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar)
        actionBar?.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
        actionBar?.show()

    }
}
```

And here is the customized fragment class which calls the `initializeCustomActionBar()` method:

```
class EnglandFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var englandViewModel: EnglandViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        englandViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EnglandViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_england, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_england)
        englandViewModel.text.observe(this, Observer {
            textView.text = it

            var mContext : FragmentActivity?  = FragmentActivity()
            mContext = this!!.getActivity() as CountriesActivity
            mContext.initializeCustomActionBar()

        })
        return root
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use an interface that the activity implements.

First define the interface in its own file, for example `CountriesActivityListener.kt`:

```
interface CountriesActivityListener {
    fun initializeCustomActionBar()
}
```

Implement the interface in the activity:

```
class CountriesActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CountriesActivityListener {

    //........

    override fun initializeCustomActionBar() {
        val actionBar: android.app.ActionBar? = actionBar
        actionBar?.let {
            it.displayOptions = DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            it.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar)
            it.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Use the interface in the fragment:

```
class EnglandFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var englandViewModel: EnglandViewModel

     // Define the reference to the interface listener:
    private lateinit var contriesActivityListener: CountriesActivityListener

    // Setup the interface listener in the onAttach override:
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        contriesActivityListener = activity as CountriesActivityListener
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        englandViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EnglandViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_england, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_england)
        englandViewModel.text.observe(this, Observer {
            textView.text = it

            // Use the interface method:
            contriesActivityListener.initializeCustomActionBar()
        })
        return root
    }
}
```

Comment: I am now finding the `initializeCustomToolBar()` method but the custom toolbar doesn't appear when i run the app

Comment: Hard to say why it wouldn't be working.  Make sure you're using a Theme that includes a default actionbar.  Another option would be to use a Theme that doesn't have a default actionbar, and put your custom Toolbar in the layout xml.  If you go that route, you could use the interface listener to modify the toolbar/actionbar from each fragment (that is what I usually do).

Comment: Thanks, I did try changing the theme to no action bar but then I got a run time error about there be a null reference to the title of the action bar.

Comment: ```java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference```

Comment: I've tried the approach that you suggested using an interface but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I edited `initializeCustomActionBar()` to:

```
fun initializeCustomActionBar() {

    val actionBar: ActionBar? = this.supportActionBar
    actionBar?.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)
    actionBar?.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
    actionBar?.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar)
}
```